# run multiple cross tabulations with function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Hi I am trying to make some  contingency tables. I want it in a function so I can use it for various columns/dataframes/combinations etc.

current I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'group' : ['A','A','B','B','C','D'],
                        'class': ['g1','g2','g2','g3','g1','g2'],
                        'total' : ['0-10','20-30','0-10','30-40','50-60','20-30'],
                        'sub' : ['1-4', '5-9','10-14', '15-19','1-4','15-19'],
                        'n': [3,14,12,11,21,9]})
```

and a function that looks like this

```
def cts(tabs, df):
    out=[]
    for col in df.loc[:,df.columns != tabs]:
        a = pd.crosstab([df[tabs]], df[col])
        out.append(a)
    return(out)
cts('group', df)
```

which works for cross tabulations for one column against the rest. But I want to add two (or more!) levels to the grouping e.g.

```
pd.crosstab([df['group'], df['class']], df['total'])
```

where total is cross tabulated against both group and class.

I think the 'tabs' var in the function should be a list of column names, but when i try and make it a list i get errors re invalid syntax. I hope this makes sense.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def cts(tabs, df):
    out=[]
    cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in tabs]
    for col in df.loc[:,cols]:
        a = pd.crosstab([df[tab] for tab in tabs], df[col])
        out.append(a)
    return(out)
```